# Grid view to display date format in MM-DD-YYYY format

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview to display date on button click depending on the checkbox(s) selected. I have used string concatenation to fetch data to manage dynamic changes at the UI. Currently, it displays in this format - `MM-DD-YYYY 12:00:00 AM`, by default but I need it in `MM-DD-YYYY` format.

With `BoundField, DataFormatString="{0:d}" HtmlEncode="False"`, I get the desired output but I can't build the dynamic SQL connection string. I have referred the tutorials and websites but most have them have provided solution with fixed SQL query or by using Gridview's "Choose Data Source" option. In my case, since its dynamic query, I can't Choose Data Source, I guess.

Is it possible to set a particular column's property of gridview to display the desired format.? Please suggest. Kindly share your thoughts with sample code (will be more helpful).

The code is as follows. The current output is attached.

Code:

```
DataTable GetData(int Count)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT [NAME], [Date], Duration FROM dbo.OnLeaveDetails WHERE @User = Username AND ";
    string whereClause = "[Leave Type] = ";

    if(CheckBox1.Checked)
        query += whereClause + "@" + <TYPE1>;
    ....
    ....

    Command = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);

    try
    {
        Conn.Open();
        Command.Parameters.Add("User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Username;

        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            Command.Parameters.Add(<TYPE>, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LeaveType[0];
        ....
        ....

        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        Conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
    catch ()
    {....}
}

protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetData(count);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `[Date]` you should use MS SQL CONVERT function:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101)
```

101 = mm/dd/yyyy

you can format your date in many ways, all of them are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Well. I just noticed that after converting, the date was properly displayed but the header displays as "Column1".

If I don't convert the date format, the header populates properly. Any suggestion to fix this.?

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date], 101) as Name`